# Cane Creek "universal" hoods and Shimano 600 (BL-6400) lever compatibility

Tags: compatibility, brake-levers

Does anyone happen to know know if these Cane Creek "universal" hoods are compatible with these vintage Shimano 600 (BL-6400) levers?

It's okay if they don't fit quite perfectly or if I have to trim them a bit to get them to fit.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you buy the correct hoods available lots of places eg https://www.velovilles.com/en/parts/Hoods/Aero-Hoods-oxid-2.html

Comment: @JoeK Because my levers are the old non-aero version, and the cable routing on mine is done through the top of the lever, not through the body. Notice there's no hole on top of the aero hoods. But I guess I could cut a small hole for the cable.

Comment: I see! Well, it's easier to make a hole than cut a curve to match the lever body in this type of rubberised material, so long as the rest of the hood fits.